# Regex for parsing version number

Tags: python, regex

How can I write a regex for parsing version numbers. I want to match numbers like: `1.000`, `1.0.00`, `1.0.0.000` but not integers `1`, `10`,`100`

Comment: unclear. Give some examples of what do you want to match and what do you won't?

Comment: So split by comma and must be a digit or an asterisk and must contain a dot then?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Sorry, but who said anything about commas?

Comment: Erm the OP, "1.000, 1.0.00" may be. I assumed the commas were part of the input, and then I realised my assumption and asked...

Comment: Just to be clear mate, are the commas part of the input. Must have a dot in it could be solved easily. Must be composed of digits, dot and asterisks only slightly more so. I'd probably use a regex for that simply to avoid testing every member of a split array for legal chars.

Comment: is all the input in the format 1.0.0.0  or can there be 1,0,0,0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?:(\d+\.[.\d]*\d+))
```

OR

```
(?:(\d+\.(?:\d+\.)*\d+))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fU3fH9/12)

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'foobar 1.000, 1.0.00, 1.0.0.000 10 100 foo bar foobar'
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?:(\d+\.(?:\d+\.)*\d+))', str)
>>> m
['1.000', '1.0.00', '1.0.0.000']
```

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko how about this [`(?:(\d+\.(?:\d\.)*\d+))`](http://regex101.com/r/fU3fH9/11)?

Comment: New one doesn't match, `1.12.1`.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it is making an assumption that you want this functionality to compare different versions of an application.

You can do this using [`distutils.version`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.version) (the docs are empty, but we can find function documentation in the [source](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Lib/distutils/version.py) )

A couple examples to help understand what we are doing:

```
>>> from distutils.version import LooseVersion, StrictVersion
>>> LooseVersion("1.0.1") < LooseVersion("1.0.2")
True
>>> StrictVersion("1.0.1") < StrictVersion("1.0.2")
True
>>> LooseVersion("1.0.10") < LooseVersion("1.0.1")
False
```

What's the difference between `LooseVersion` and `StrictVersion`? With `LooseVersion` you can compare "real world" versions like this:

```
>>> LooseVersion("2.1-rc1") < LooseVersion("2.2")
True
```

Whereas `StrictVersion` doesn't allow alphabetic characters

```
>>> StrictVersion("2.1-rc1") < StrictVersion("2.2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.parse(vstring)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 107, in parse
    raise ValueError, "invalid version number '%s'" % vstring
ValueError: invalid version number '2.1-rc1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(\d+\\.)?(\d+\\.)?(\\*|\d+)$
```

Answer (score 1):

**Clarification**: I'm assuming you want to *parse* the numbers, not just *match* them.

Why use regexes when a simple split will work just fine?

`'1.3.4.*'.split('.')
 # => ['1', '3', '4', '*']`

If you want to ensure that there is at least one dot in the string, check the array length to ensure it is larger than 1.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, where does it say they want to split by commas? And a split will tell you if there are if there is more than 1 part.

Comment: @Tonyhopkinson That's simple, just check the length of teh resulting array and see if it's greater than one.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson That was not clear from the OP (there was no mention of matching, only parsing). But split still works, matches with at least one dot will have len(matches) > 1.

Comment: 1.0,1.2 is what it says. I did assume that was the input, and while the question is titled parsing, it does say matching in the body. I may be assuming, or you may be, perhaps we all are, which is why I asked for clarification from the OP.