# regex to match version number

Tags: python, regex

hi everyone i have data parsed that i want to match.

i have list two strings i have parsed with:

```
        technologytitle=technologytitle.lower()
        vulntitle=vulntitle.lower()
        ree1=re.split(technologytitle, vulntitle)
```

This produces the following:

```
['\nmultiple cross-site scripting (xss) vulnerabilities in', '9.0.1 and earlier\n\n\n\n\n']
```

I am now trying to formulate writing re.match to match the second value with:

```
    ree2=re.match(r'^[0-9].[0-9]*$', ree1[1])

    print("ree2 {}".format(ree2))
```

however this is returning `None` .

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: You can write it as `\d+(?:\.\d+)+\b` with re.match https://regex101.com/r/rNlnSu/1 See posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698919/regexp-for-matching-executable-version-number and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629867/regex-for-parsing-version-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unclear if you wanted the whole string, or individual parts, but you can do both without `^` or `$`

```
import re

regex = r'((?P<major>\d+)\.(?P<minor>\d+)\.(?P<patch>\d+))'
s = '9.0.1 and earlier\n\n\n\n\n'

matches = re.search(regex, s)
print(matches.group(0))
for v in ['major', 'minor', 'patch']:
    print(v, matches.group(v))
```

Output

```
9.0.1
major 9
minor 0
patch 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this one and it worked for me since dollar sign means the end of pattern and your pattern does not end with a number between 0-9 then it gives you none

```
regexPattern = "[0-9].*[0-9]"
```

Comment: The explanation is correct but the regex is wrong; it will capture anything between the first number and the last.

Comment: yes because i wasn't sure about how many numbers could be among those two number

Comment: You are accepting non-numbers, too; like "4 but not quite 5" or "3.141259 but we can round that to an even 13"

Comment: You are right so this pattern is better i guess 
'regexPattern = "[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]*"'

Comment: That seems rather too specific. The other answer does a better job, anyway.